# send cross domain request using python Requests: HTTP for Humans

Tags: python, django, python-requests

i am using Requests: HTTP for Humans cross domain request using python but i am getting internal server error 500 
**My Code:**

```
def request_post(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    method_name = request.POST.get('method')
    url_data   = request.POST.get('url')
    response_data = {}
    resp = requests.get(str(url_data))
    response_data['status']=resp.status_code
    #response_data['']
    return HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(response_data),
            content_type="application/json"
        )    
else:
    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps({"nothing to see": "this isn't happening"}),
        content_type="application/json"
    )
```

**error code**

```
500: KeyError at /api/request_post/
''

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/request_post/
Django Version: 1.11
Python Executable: C:\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.1
Python Path: ['C:\\runscope', 'C:\\Python\\Python36-32\\python36.zip', 'C:\\Python\\Python36-32\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib', 'C:\\Python\\Python36-32', 'C:\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-34.4.1-py3.6.egg', 'C:\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib\\site-packages\\unirest-1.1.7-py3.6.egg']
Server time: Thu, 13 Apr 2017 10:54:31 +0000
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'test_runscope']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Traceback:  

File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\runscope\test_runscope\views.py" in request_post
  38.         #response_data['']

Exception Type: KeyError at /api/request_post/
Exception Value: ''
Request information:
USER: AnonymousUser

GET: No GET data

POST:
csrfmiddlewaretoken = '9qMcPnYuHbSdR9N4RlVBthqTwcb2iMew9UGntWSvlfhKGhDeBbTBKqetFCFTif0O'
method = 'GET'
url = 'http://200.98.68.197/task/itens_name/sofa'

FILES: No FILES data

COOKIES:
csrftoken = 'Tuxviz4JT21FARmtg42amrf6Y0kRW1HXTYrGW8YKx6qcpZcD0U0aDA3G7qOIWutf'

META:
ALLUSERSPROFILE = 'C:\\ProgramData'
APPDATA = 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Roaming'
COMMONPROGRAMFILES = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files'
COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86) = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files'
COMMONPROGRAMW6432 = 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files'
COMPUTERNAME = 'E2'
COMSPEC = 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe'
CONTENT_LENGTH = '153'
CONTENT_TYPE = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
CSRF_COOKIE = 'Tuxviz4JT21FARmtg42amrf6Y0kRW1HXTYrGW8YKx6qcpZcD0U0aDA3G7qOIWutf'
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = 'runscope.settings'
GATEWAY_INTERFACE = 'CGI/1.1'
HOMEDRIVE = 'C:'
HOMEPATH = '\\Users\\USER'
HTTP_ACCEPT = '*/*'
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING = 'gzip, deflate, br'
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE = 'en-US,en;q=0.8'
HTTP_CONNECTION = 'keep-alive'
HTTP_COOKIE = 'csrftoken=Tuxviz4JT21FARmtg42amrf6Y0kRW1HXTYrGW8YKx6qcpZcD0U0aDA3G7qOIWutf'
HTTP_HOST = '127.0.0.1:8000'
HTTP_ORIGIN = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
HTTP_REFERER = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/'
HTTP_USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36'
HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH = 'XMLHttpRequest'
LOCALAPPDATA = 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local'
LOGONSERVER = '\\\\E2'
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS = '4'
ONEDRIVE = 'C:\\Users\\USER\\OneDrive'
OS = 'Windows_NT'
PATH = 'C:\\Python\\Python36-32\\Scripts\\;C:\\Python\\Python36-32\\;C:\\ProgramData\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\WINDOWS;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\AMD\\ATI.ACE\\Core-Static;C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Skype\\Phone\\;E:\\xampp\\php;C:\\ProgramData\\ComposerSetup\\bin;C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm;C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Roaming\\Composer\\vendor\\bin'
PATHEXT = '.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW'
PATH_INFO = '/api/request_post/'
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE = 'x86'
PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 = 'AMD64'
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER = 'AMD64 Family 22 Model 48 Stepping 1, AuthenticAMD'
PROCESSOR_LEVEL = '22'
PROCESSOR_REVISION = '3001'
PROGRAMDATA = 'C:\\ProgramData'
PROGRAMFILES = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)'
PROGRAMFILES(X86) = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)'
PROGRAMW6432 = 'C:\\Program Files'
PROMPT = '$P$G'
PSMODULEPATH = 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Modules'
PUBLIC = 'C:\\Users\\Public'
QUERY_STRING = ''
REMOTE_ADDR = '127.0.0.1'
REMOTE_HOST = ''
REQUEST_METHOD = 'POST'
RUN_MAIN = 'true'
SCRIPT_NAME = ''
SERVER_NAME = 'e2'
SERVER_PORT = '8000'
SERVER_PROTOCOL = 'HTTP/1.1'
SERVER_SOFTWARE = 'WSGIServer/0.2'
SESSIONNAME = 'Console'
SYSTEMDRIVE = 'C:'
SYSTEMROOT = 'C:\\WINDOWS'
TEMP = 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp'
TMP = 'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp'
USERDOMAIN = 'E2'
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE = 'E2'
USERNAME = 'Aslam'
USERPROFILE = 'C:\\Users\\USER'
WINDIR = 'C:\\WINDOWS'
wsgi.errors = <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stderr>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
wsgi.file_wrapper = ''
wsgi.input = <_io.BufferedReader name=956>
wsgi.multiprocess = False
wsgi.multithread = True
wsgi.run_once = False
wsgi.url_scheme = 'http'
wsgi.version = 

Settings:
Using settings module runscope.settings
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES = {}
ADMINS = []
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
APPEND_SLASH = True
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = '********************'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'
BASE_DIR = 'C:\\runscope'
CACHES = {'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache'}}
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS = 'default'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX = '********************'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS = 600
CSRF_COOKIE_AGE = 31449600
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = 'csrftoken'
CSRF_COOKIE_PATH = '/'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW = 'django.views.csrf.csrf_failure'
CSRF_HEADER_NAME = 'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN'
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = []
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = False
DATABASES = {'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 'NAME': 'C:\\runscope\\db.sqlite3', 'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False, 'AUTOCOMMIT': True, 'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0, 'OPTIONS': {}, 'TIME_ZONE': None, 'USER': '', 'PASSWORD': '********************', 'HOST': '', 'PORT': '', 'TEST': {'CHARSET': None, 'COLLATION': None, 'NAME': None, 'MIRROR': None}}}
DATABASE_ROUTERS = []
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 2621440
DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_NUMBER_FIELDS = 1000
DATETIME_FORMAT = 'N j, Y, P'
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', '%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M', '%m/%d/%y']
DATE_FORMAT = 'N j, Y'
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y', '%b %d %Y', '%b %d, %Y', '%d %b %Y', '%d %b, %Y', '%B %d %Y', '%B %d, %Y', '%d %B %Y', '%d %B, %Y']
DEBUG = True
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = False
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = '.'
DEFAULT_CHARSET = 'utf-8'
DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE = 'text/html'
DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_REPORTER_FILTER = 'django.views.debug.SafeExceptionReporterFilter'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'webmaster@localhost'
DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE = ''
DEFAULT_TABLESPACE = ''
DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS = []
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '********************'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_SSL_CERTFILE = None
EMAIL_SSL_KEYFILE = '********************'
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = '[Django] '
EMAIL_TIMEOUT = None
EMAIL_USE_LOCALTIME = False
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
FILE_CHARSET = 'utf-8'
FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS = None
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = ['django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler', 'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler']
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 2621440
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = None
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR = None
FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK = 0
FIXTURE_DIRS = []
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = None
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH = None
FORM_RENDERER = 'django.forms.renderers.DjangoTemplates'
IGNORABLE_404_URLS = []
INSTALLED_APPS = ['django.contrib.admin', 'django.contrib.auth', 'django.contrib.contenttypes', 'django.contrib.sessions', 'django.contrib.messages', 'django.contrib.staticfiles', 'django.contrib.sites', 'test_runscope']
INTERNAL_IPS = []
LANGUAGES = [('af', 'Afrikaans'), ('ar', 'Arabic'), ('ast', 'Asturian'), ('az', 'Azerbaijani'), ('bg', 'Bulgarian'), ('be', 'Belarusian'), ('bn', 'Bengali'), ('br', 'Breton'), ('bs', 'Bosnian'), ('ca', 'Catalan'), ('cs', 'Czech'), ('cy', 'Welsh'), ('da', 'Danish'), ('de', 'German'), ('dsb', 'Lower Sorbian'), ('el', 'Greek'), ('en', 'English'), ('en-au', 'Australian English'), ('en-gb', 'British English'), ('eo', 'Esperanto'), ('es', 'Spanish'), ('es-ar', 'Argentinian Spanish'), ('es-co', 'Colombian Spanish'), ('es-mx', 'Mexican Spanish'), ('es-ni', 'Nicaraguan Spanish'), ('es-ve', 'Venezuelan Spanish'), ('et', 'Estonian'), ('eu', 'Basque'), ('fa', 'Persian'), ('fi', 'Finnish'), ('fr', 'French'), ('fy', 'Frisian'), ('ga', 'Irish'), ('gd', 'Scottish Gaelic'), ('gl', 'Galician'), ('he', 'Hebrew'), ('hi', 'Hindi'), ('hr', 'Croatian'), ('hsb', 'Upper Sorbian'), ('hu', 'Hungarian'), ('ia', 'Interlingua'), ('id', 'Indonesian'), ('io', 'Ido'), ('is', 'Icelandic'), ('it', 'Italian'), ('ja', 'Japanese'), ('ka', 'Georgian'), ('kk', 'Kazakh'), ('km', 'Khmer'), ('kn', 'Kannada'), ('ko', 'Korean'), ('lb', 'Luxembourgish'), ('lt', 'Lithuanian'), ('lv', 'Latvian'), ('mk', 'Macedonian'), ('ml', 'Malayalam'), ('mn', 'Mongolian'), ('mr', 'Marathi'), ('my', 'Burmese'), ('nb', 'Norwegian Bokmål'), ('ne', 'Nepali'), ('nl', 'Dutch'), ('nn', 'Norwegian Nynorsk'), ('os', 'Ossetic'), ('pa', 'Punjabi'), ('pl', 'Polish'), ('pt', 'Portuguese'), ('pt-br', 'Brazilian Portuguese'), ('ro', 'Romanian'), ('ru', 'Russian'), ('sk', 'Slovak'), ('sl', 'Slovenian'), ('sq', 'Albanian'), ('sr', 'Serbian'), ('sr-latn', 'Serbian Latin'), ('sv', 'Swedish'), ('sw', 'Swahili'), ('ta', 'Tamil'), ('te', 'Telugu'), ('th', 'Thai'), ('tr', 'Turkish'), ('tt', 'Tatar'), ('udm', 'Udmurt'), ('uk', 'Ukrainian'), ('ur', 'Urdu'), ('vi', 'Vietnamese'), ('zh-hans', 'Simplified Chinese'), ('zh-hant', 'Traditional Chinese')]
LANGUAGES_BIDI = ['he', 'ar', 'fa', 'ur']
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_AGE = None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME = 'django_language'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_PATH = '/'
LOCALE_PATHS = []
LOGGING = {}
LOGGING_CONFIG = 'logging.config.dictConfig'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/profile/'
LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = None
MANAGERS = []
MEDIA_ROOT = ''
MEDIA_URL = ''
MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage'
MIDDLEWARE = ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = ['django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware']
MIGRATION_MODULES = {}
MONTH_DAY_FORMAT = 'F j'
NUMBER_GROUPING = 0
PASSWORD_HASHERS = '********************'
PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS = '********************'
PREPEND_WWW = False
PROJECT_DIR = 'C:\\runscope\\runscope'
ROOT_URLCONF = 'runscope.urls'
SECRET_KEY = '********************'
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = False
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = False
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = False
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = False
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 0
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = None
SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT = []
SECURE_SSL_HOST = None
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False
SERVER_EMAIL = 'root@localhost'
SESSION_CACHE_ALIAS = 'default'
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 1209600
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN = None
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'sessionid'
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH = '/'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = False
SESSION_FILE_PATH = None
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = False
SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.JSONSerializer'
SETTINGS_MODULE = 'runscope.settings'
SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT = 'm/d/Y P'
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT = 'm/d/Y'
SIGNING_BACKEND = 'django.core.signing.TimestampSigner'
SILENCED_SYSTEM_CHECKS = []
STATICFILES_DIRS = 'C:\\runscope\\staticfiles'
STATICFILES_FINDERS = ['django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder', 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder']
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT = 'C:\\runscope\\static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
TEMPLATES = [{'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates', 'DIRS': [], 'APP_DIRS': True, 'OPTIONS': {'context_processors': ['django.template.context_processors.debug', 'django.template.context_processors.request', 'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth', 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages']}}]
TEST_NON_SERIALIZED_APPS = []
TEST_RUNNER = 'django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner'
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = ','
TIME_FORMAT = 'P'
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%H:%M:%S', '%H:%M:%S.%f', '%H:%M']
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_ETAGS = False
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR = False
USE_TZ = True
USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = False
USE_X_FORWARDED_PORT = False
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'runscope.wsgi.application'
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT = 'F Y'
```

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your
Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will
display a standard page generated by the handler for this status code

Comment: You need to show the actual text of the error.

Comment: in console showing error like:

Comment: error 500: KeyError at /api/request_post/

Comment: Still needs more detail. What key is giving an error? What line is the error happening? If you would just post the full traceback, we would have that information.

Comment: now i am updating data and also put error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it seems as if the following line is interpreted:

`#response_data['']`

Because the traceback of the exception you get points to this line:

> Traceback:
>
> File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
>     41.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
>     187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
>     185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "C:\runscope\test_runscope\views.py" in request_post
>     38.         #response_data['']

See the last line?

> File "C:\runscope\test_runscope\views.py" in request_post 38. #response_data['']

The associated exception is:

> Exception Type: KeyError at /api/request_post/
>
> Exception Value: ''

The exception value might be your "key" that you used in this line:

`#response_data['']`

If you access a dictionary like this and the key is not present in the dictionary you get an `KeyError`.

So you should remove that line and try again.

See: https://wiki.python.org/moin/KeyError

Comment: thank to your valuable answer but i think problem for put resp.headers in json data

Comment: yes i remove this line and work fine but i want to also response header

Comment: how to parse this content  i am trying json.load but not working{'Date': 'Thu, 13 Apr 2017 12:02:50 GMT', 'Server': 'Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)', 'X-Powered-By': 'PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17', 'Set-Cookie': 'PHPSESSID=0q4hnijd50e43j93ibc7bimmu1; path=/', 'Expires': 'Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT', 'Cache-Control': 'no-store, no-cache,'}

Comment: @jhon I am glad to hear that my answer helped you. Would you mind accepting it as the right answer and create a new question for your follow up question? Every Stackoverflow question should be as precise as possible. Mixing multiple questions and multiple answers in one question is not how Stackoverflow questions are supposed to be. If you want to know more about how to ask questions look at this help article: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask